# React: How to use an up to date state with Firestore onSnapshot and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to update my state adding new messages from `Firestore onSnapshot` to the existing array of messages but inside `onSnapshot` I only have access to the state when the subscription was done.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const ref = firestore()
    .collection('Msg_Messages')

  return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot =>
    setMessages(messages => messages.concat(querySnapshot.docs)))
}, [])
```

**When I receive a message I get:**

```
OnMountMessages + lastMessage
```

**instead of**

```
OnMountMessages + allMessagesSinceMount + lastMessage
```

I guess becase `onSnapshot` creates his own copy of `messages` and `setMessages`. The only solution I can think about is to use Redux and keep the state outside of the component, but is there an other solution?

Comment: Regarding your guess - sounds likely. Try changing `(querySnapshot => ...` to `(function (querySnapshot) {...`.

Comment: Thanks but it unfortunately produces the same effect

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your anonymous function to .onSnapshot is capturing a stale version of messages in it's closure. As you know, you *can* pass a function to useState, but I think the compiler is getting confused on the conflicting name.  Try this:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const ref = firestore()
    .collection('Msg_Messages')

  return ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot =>
    setMessages(prevmessages => prevmessages.concat(querySnapshot.docs)))
}, [])
```

in this case, 'prevmessages' comes from useState as the immediately preceding value of it's state - and doesn't get confused with it's resulting state value 'messages'

(Oh, and also: for a QuerySnapshot, the property is ".docs", not ".data")

Comment: Thanks for your response, you pointed the problem very well, however the solution you provided does not solve it. (I edited the .docs part, it was a mistake simplifying the question for the purpose of the question.)

Comment: The .onSnapshot(next()) will be called *at least once* with the all the current documents in the collection.  If any change or are added, it will be called again returning ALL THE DOCUMENTS, not just the changes.  You write "when I receive a message" - how exactly is this happening?  Another instance is writing to the Firestore?  Does the callback get called more than once?  Seems to be a LOT left out of the question...

Comment: The problem does not come from how I handle the onSnaphot method, indeed the first messages set all the preexisting messages but then every message added is then replaced by the next one. Yes other messages arrive because another instance is writing to Firestore and yes the callback is called more than once

Comment: Unfortunately, there just isn't enough in the question to be able to construct an answer without wildly speculating on the "unseen" parts.  For example: querySnapshot.docs property is NOT an array of your documents - it's an array of  QueryDocumentSnapshot , and  the QueryDocumentSnapshot .data() method returns the actual document contents.  Impossible to know if that is anticipated elsewhere in your code.